# What happens when .h & .cpp Doxygen tags conflict?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have .h & .cpp files in my project that have /brief tags in both locations: what does doxygen do when there is a conflict between the 2 potential locations for documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) :

> Having more than one brief or detailed description is allowed (but not recommended, as the order in which the descriptions will appear is not specified).

And the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdbrief) for the brief command:

> If multiple \brief commands are present they will be joined.